# How to keep the ExpandableListView Opened?

Tags: android, click, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am working on the ExpandableListView I have completed the work, now only one thing that I want to do is I don't want the ListView to be DropDown on click of the Expandable List View rather I want to show it opened with all the Items displayed inside  without performing any click on them.

Can anyone tell me how can i do that particularly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do this for every one of the groups to expand them:

```
listView1.expandGroup(int groupPosition);
```

If you want to prevent group collapse, then do this:

```
listView1.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener()
{
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
    {
        listView1.expandGroup(itemPosition);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Solution:- To Keep The Expandable list in Expanded mode all the times
It is actually very simple you dont need to do anything but just put this one line in your getGroupView of your adapter and your expandablelistview always be in opened/expanded state:--

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        your_expandableListview.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        return v;
    }
```

This works for sure... Enjoy..!

Answer (score 2):

#### Open `ExpandableListView` Group:

```
 listView.expandGroup(itemPosition);
```

#### Collapse `ExpandableListView` Group:

```
 listView.collapseGroup(itemPosition);
```