# loading high amounts of views programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, for-loop, android-listview, android-view

I have a for loop within a for loop within a for loop (3 for loops).  Each for loop loads at least one view in them some load more than 1.  All of the views(textviews, imageviews) are loaded into a relative layout or a linear layout and those layouts are all loaded into one linear layout and all of that is in a scrollview.

I know confusing and probably the worst way to do this. I have looked up different things most of them are listview related such as the endless adapter or lazy loading.  I don't think listview will work for what i am trying to do. I have memory problems doing it this way.

> *So I guess what my question is will ListView be the right direction to go?  Will i still be able to use my for-for-for loops?*

***Consider each block to represent a layout (each of layout consist of textviews, only the black boxes have imageviews and textviews) and also consider each color to represent a for loop.  The black borders represent the linear layout that all of these views and other layouts get shoved into.  Keep in mind it's not always going to be the same amount of black boxes beneath the red and blue boxes***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if i really got what you want do here but in my opinion u **should** use an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html).

Doing this with layouts as you stated cause memory problems because you are loading a complex hierarchy of views, android is drawing all the views (even the ones that are not visible yet) and none of your views are reused.

Using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and defining different types of [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) you should be able to do what you need.

For instance lets say each red box is one [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). So from your scheme you'll have 2 [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html), lets call them "ViewOneBlueTwoBlack" and "ViewOneBlueThreeBlack". Also lets say you have more types of [AdapterViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) "ViewTwoBlueTwoBlack", "ViewTwoBlueFiveBlack", etc...
Now what you need to do is handle in your Adapter the conditions to know when each type of AdapterView should be load.

Or even better if you consider that the redboxes are sections and then the blue boxes become your [AdapterViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html).

You can find a nice tutorial on [ListViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) here : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Also your scheme looks a lot like a [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) check it out just in case.

Comment: I like your idea with creating different adapterviews I might just end up doing that.  The expandablelistview is some what related but expandablelistview seems to create drop down items which i don't want.

Comment: You can use ExpandableListView without using the collapse feature, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978434/how-to-keep-the-expandablelistview-opened. In http://stackoverflow.com/a/29834484/665823 you can find an inplementation and a pic of how it looks like. You'll see why your scheme made me think of that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitly used a ListView and an adpater.

You can have diffenet view type in your ListView. To do so you should have an adapter like this :

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private static int HEADER_TYPE = 0;
     private static int CONTENT_TYPE_1 = 1;
     private static int CONTENT_TYPE_2 = 2;

     @Override
     public int getViewTypeCount() {
          return 3;
     }

     @Override
     public int getItemViewType(int position) {
          if (header)
              return HEADER_TYPE;
          else if (content_type_1)
              return CONTENT_TYPE_1;
          else
              return CONTENT_TYPE_2;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           if (getItemViewType(position) == HEADER_TYPE) {
                   //make header view
           } else if (getItemViewType(position) == CONTENT_TYPE_1 {
                  //make content view
                  //be careful position is the position in the list view
           } else {
                  //make content view
                  //be careful position is the position in the list view
           return convertView;
      }
}
```

You should be careful when accessing your datas in getView, the postion is the position in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

> *"So I guess what my question is will ListView be the right direction to go? Will i still be able to use my for-for-for loops?"*

Answer is, right direction depends upon your scenario if your objective can be achieved with both then see which method has least views or widgets in your case there are many layouts but if you use ListView there might be one. Bt in developing the best way is any way which fullfil customer's requirements..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a table layout for this. Declare a table layout in your xml file, and add views dynamically.

I gave a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157802/how-to-make-android-layout-like-marksheets/31160943#31160943), you can customize the solution to have only one view in row and align accordingly.